# как из String в библиотеке gson сделать json и перевести в массив?

Tags: java, json, gson

[image]

Я взял с сайта эти данные. Но не могу взять данные именно из столбика viewers и все никнаймы сделать массив.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала из текста надо получить `JsonObject` содержащий весь json:
`JsonObject root = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonObject();`,
`json` может быть строкой, `Reader` (Например `InputStreamReader` или `FileReader`), либо `JsonReader` (Используется очень редко). Если парсить в программе надо много раз `JsonParser` можно сохранить, а не создавать каждый раз.

После получения объекта из него можно получить `viewers` в виде `JsonArray`:
 `JsonArray viewers = root.getAsJsonArray("veiwers");`
У `JsonArray` есть метод `get(int)` который позволяет получить определённый элемент. Также есть метод `forEach(Consumer)` который позволяет провести итерации по каждому элементу. Преобразовывать его в обычный массив обычно не требуется, но если надо то это можно сделать с помощью Stream API из Java 8: `StreamSupport.stream(arr.spliterator(), false).map(JsonElement::getAsString).toArray(String[]::new);`.

Comment: `JsonObject root = new JsonParser().parse(text).getAsJsonObject();`
`JsonArray viewers = root.getAsJsonArray("veiwers");`
`System.out.println(viewers.get(0).toString());`
Вот так написал, и выдает ошибку Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException.
И как использовать forEach()?

Comment: NPE из-за того что я слегка опечатался, в `getAsJsonArray` должно быть не `veiwers` а `viewers`. Также вместо `toString` после `get` стоит использовать `getAsString`. Использование `forEach`: Java8: `.forEach(e -> {
String s = e.getAsString();
//Действия с s который является текущим элементом (Будет вызвано поочерёдно для каждого элемента)
}`
До Java 8:
`.forEach(new Consumer<JsonElement>() {
 @Override
 public void accept(JsonElement e) {
 String s = e.getAsString();
 //Действия с s который является текущим элементом (Будет вызвано поочерёдно для каждого элемента)
 }
});`

Comment: `JsonObject root = new JsonParser().parse(text).getAsJsonObject();`
`JsonArray viewers = root.getAsJsonArray("viewers");`
`System.out.println(viewers.get(0).getAsString());`
Сделал так и ошибка `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`. Пишет что ошибка в этой строчке `System.out.println(viewers.get(0).getAsString());` и так же ошибку вадает тут `viewers.forEach(e -> {
     String s = e.getAsString();
        System.out.println(s);
        });`

Comment: А, неправильно посмотрел на входной json, `JsonArray viewers = root.getAsJsonObject("chatters").getAsJsonArray("viewers");`.